# What does this pointer mean actually

Tags: c

```
typedef uint8_t A[3];
A *p;
```

I am not able to comprehend what this pointer `p` here actually is?

```
A b;
```

is

```
uint8_t b[3];
```

So is

```
A *p;
```

is

```
uint8_t (*p)[3];
```

Is my understanding correct???

If `typedef` happens to just do a mere replacement for the typedef'ed tokens then how this is done? Can someone explain?